# NP-hardness of particular problem

Tags: algorithms, np-complete

Suppose given two sets $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\},\{b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n\}$ of positive real numbers.
We try to find a subset $I\subseteq\{1,2,3\dots,n\}$ such that:
$\sum_{i\in I}b_i$ maximized and $\sum_{i\in I}a_i\leq 5$.

I think this problem is NP-hard but I can't reduce from famous problem like partition problem. Any help will be apricated.

Answer (score 2):

This is the optimization form of the 0-1 Knapsack problem ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)).

In a 0-1 Knapsack problem, you have a set of items, each item having a weight and value. You have to select a set of items such that the sum of the values is maximized, but that the total weight of the items does not exceed the total capacity of the Knapsack. Here, the set $\{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n\}$ corresponds to the set of weights and the set $\{b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_n\}$ to the values, with the maximum weight being $5$.

The problem you posit is not a decision problem, and therefore is outside the classical definition of NP-hardness. However, it's easily converted into a decision problem asking whether a total value $V$ can be reached without exceeding the weight limit $W$. This version of the problem is NP-complete.

Comment: So, my problem can solved in poly time?

Comment: @Mohammad.Rostami If $P=NP$. Otherwise no, though special cases of the problem may have polynomial time algorithms as usual.

Comment: If $P\neq NP$ can you explain why my problem has no poly time solution?

Comment: @Mohammad.Rostami Because the problem is NP-complete. If the problem (converted into a decision problem) has a polynomial solution, it implies $P=NP$. By contraposition, $P \neq NP$ implies no polynomial time solution to the problem.

Comment: How you find out this is a NP-complete problem? Can you explain it?

Comment: @Mohammad.Rostami You can find several proofs online. A succinct one: The Subset Sum problem can be reduced to a Knapsack Problem. Treat the input multiset of integers as the weights and values of items (each item having the same weight as its value) and the target sum as the knapsack's maximum weight and minimum value. The knapsack can be packed if and only if the subset sum can equal the target value. Since subset sum is NP-hard, knapsack is therefore too. (Knapsack is also NP, which probably doesn't require much in the way of proving, hence NP-complete)